# dropdown menu outside of shadowbox

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating a shadowbox on my website that will pop up and allow users to pick from a number of options including some in submenus.  The content within the shadowbox is going to be pretty extensive, so it needs to be able to scroll vertically and not scroll horizontally.

The problem I have is that the submenus are supposed to pop out to the right of the list and overflow to the outside of the shadowbox.  This worked until I implemented `overflow-y: scroll;` in the CSS.  Now, even if I use `overflow-x: visible;` it still acts as though the x-axis should scroll.

Has anyone encountered this problem before or have any tips on how to approach it?

[try messing with a jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/neJ8f/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#collapse-scroll:

> The computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ are the same as
>   their specified values, except that some combinations with ‘visible’
>   are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is
>   ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’.

I can't think of anything to solve this issue using CSS only, but it should be possible with JavaScript if dropdowns are outside the block with `overflow: auto`